# Change Read More in Child theme

Tags: links, blog, read-more

Im like 99% done with my multisite.

The only thing left to do is to change the read more link on the child theme. But I can't get it done.

Main site (Dutch): www.jeroenbrugman.com
2nd site(english): www.jeroenbrugman.com/en/

I need to change the read more text on the 2nd site. But I can't get it done.

Main site functions.php code:

```
if ( !function_exists( 'modify_read_more_link' )) {
  add_filter( 'the_content_more_link', 'modify_read_more_link' );
function modify_read_more_link() {
return '<a class="more-link" href="' . get_permalink() . '">Lees meer</a>';
}
}
```

2nd site functions.php code:

```
  add_filter( 'the_content_more_link', 'modify_read_more_link' );
function modify_read_more_link() {
return '<a class="more-link" href="' . get_permalink() . '">Read more</a>';
}
```

But the 2nd site still shows 'Lees Meer' from the main site.. How can I get this to work?

Kind Regards

Comment: Which one is the parent theme and which one is the child?

Comment: Main site is the parent. 2nd site is the child. Sorry for not clarifying this.

Comment: What you are doing should work. There is something else happening. What happens if you completely comment out the parent `modify_read_more_link()` function (just for debugging)?

Comment: @s_ha_dum What do you exactly mean? I removed the modify_read_more_link() after the_content_more_link but that did;t work

Comment: So what happened exactly? I am try to get you to debug and provide additional information. "That didn't work" doesn't help.

Comment: http://pastie.org/private/yog6uquoi0isad47j9xaw (too long for comment)   This did show up in my error_log which shows some errors.

Answer (score 0):

How about calling the 2nd function like this:

```
add_filter( 'the_content_more_link', 'modify_read_more_link_en' );
function modify_read_more_link_en() {...
```

??

Comment: Didn't work :( I tried soo many different codes.

Comment: Been googling like crazy. Nothing what I found has helped.